# Anonymous User - Displaying User Information

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display my users information but I am getting anonymous user as my output;
[Anonymous User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4urZ.png)

My code in my views.py is as follows;

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form' : form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', args)

def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render (request, 'accounts/profile.html',args)
```

I am over-riding the UserCreationForm, my code in forms.py is;

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        }


    def save(self,commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

    if commit:
        user.save()
        return user
```

My profile.html where I want my profile information to be displayed is;

```
{% block head %}

<title> User Profile </title>

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
<p>
  <h1> {{user}}</h1>
  <h3>First Name: {{user.first_name}}</h3>
  <h3>Last Name: {{user.last_name}}</h3>
  <h3>Email: {{user.email}}</h3>
</p>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Really not sure where I am going wrong any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure a user is logged in? Are you able to view the admin?

Comment: You register a user but never log that user in.

Comment: I fixed the above problem but now my issue is that even if a different user is logged in only the admin user details are being displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must decorate your `def view_profile(request):` with [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required), otherwise Django will serve this request also to Anonymous users.

Also note that if you have (or add) `django.core.context_processors.request` to your `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`
(or `settings.TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']` depending your django version) you can use `{{request.user}}` in your template without create specific entry in context.